# Marketo Rest API export custom object records

Tags: marketo

Does anyone know how to export all custom object records from Marketo Custom Object using REST API? I read the documentation but it looks like I can only query some of the records (I couldn't get it working) and I need to export all of them. Any ideas?

http://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/lead-database/custom-objects/
http://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/endpoint-reference/lead-database-endpoint-reference/#!/Custom_Objects/getCustomObjectsUsingGET

Comment: How many Custom Object records do you have in total and how many do you manage to fetch? Also, are you using filtering parameters or want to get all COs unfiltered?

Comment: As in the question, I need to fetch all of them, but without filter, it won't let me sent the query